# Creating directories with regex same in url structure

Tags: php, regex, download, directory-structure

I will mass download thousands of images from a server. 
My problem is : filenames are same and they are located in different directories.
Ex: 
http://domain.com/images/upload/2014/09/SKU00123/1.jpg
http://domain.com/images/upload/2014/09/SKU1501/1.jpg

I want to download them with the same directory structure. 
c:\images\upload\2014\09\SKU00123\1.jpg
I can take the file name with basename command but i couldn't find a way to get the directory structure. I need php to create directories and save the files to that destination.
Is there a way to change the url structure to directory structure? Maybe with regex?

Answer (score 1):

For the next time, please show us some PHP code. Have you already tried something?!

...You can easily do this in 2 steps:

1. Use `parse_url` to find the path(/images/upload/2014/etc..) of the URL.
2. Use `mkdir` with the recursive parameter to create these directories on your own system.